# What does Visual Basic without Forms called as?

Tags: vba, vb.net, automation

I'm a mechanical engineering learning how to automate NX software which uses VB.net language. But it won't allows to use a userform like in MS Excel Macro. For an example, if I need an input box I can't drag it from userform menu instead I will use InputBox() code. My doubt is what does this kind of Visual basic program is known as? I need the exact word for this. Kindly help me. Thanks in Advance!

I tried Googling but I don't got anything.

Comment: Are you thinking of `VBScript`?

Comment: VBA and vb.net are quite different things, update your question wit the correct tags.  Assuming it is in fact vb.net are you referring to the difference between a console app vs a winforms app?